# android.view.InflateException: Error inflating class fragment in PopMainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using pop up dialog on clicking the mapButton id.In that pop up dialog Map have to be shown.I am getting Error `inflating class fragment exception` on clicking the mapbutton.Below I have posted the relevant codes.

I have tried many Stackoverflow posts regarding to these issue.Nothing solved my issue.

**Stacktrace:**

```
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380): Process: com.android.steveactiivty, PID: 13380
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):    at com.android.steveactiivty.PopMainActivity$1.onClick(PopMainActivity.java:52)
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.fragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.android.steveactiivty-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:665)
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:65)
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):    ... 15 more
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):        ... 21 more
02-02 09:27:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13380):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

**PopMainActivity.java:**

```
 public class PopMainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
 Button mapButton,dismiss;  
    View popupView;

    // Google Map
        private GoogleMap googleMap;

        EditText editLong,editLat;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")  
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mapButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mapButton);


        editLat = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editLat);
        editLong = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editLong);

        mapButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
                        .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_main, null);

                final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                getPopUpView();

                SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.popMapFrag);

                // Getting a reference to the map
                googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();

                // popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);


                // Setting a click event handler for the map
                googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {  

                        // Creating a marker
                        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();   

                        // Setting the position for the marker
                        markerOptions.position(latLng);

                        // Setting the title for the marker.
                        // This will be displayed on taping the marker
                        markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude + " : " + latLng.longitude);

                        editLat.setText(Double.toString((double) latLng.latitude));
                        editLong.setText(Double.toString((double) latLng.longitude));

                        // Clears the previously touched position
                        googleMap.clear();

                        // Animating to the touched position
                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

                        // Placing a marker on the touched position
                        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                    }
                });
                    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(mapButton, 50, -30);

            }

            private void getPopUpView() {

            //  dismiss=(Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);


            }
        });
 }
 }
```

**popup_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/popMapFrag"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

       </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you added corresponding support library?

Comment: Is the 't' after the close tag of fragment a copy paste error?

Comment: @brainfreak yes copy paste error sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
                    .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

with:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
```

Never use `LayoutInflate.from()` unless you know exactly *why* you are using `LayoutInflater.from()`. In particular, never use `LayoutInflater.from()` when you are trying to inflate a layout that has a `<fragment>` element in it. Also, never use `LayoutInflater.from()` if you have a custom theme. If you are working with an activity, always get your `LayoutInflater` from `getLayoutInflater()`.

In this case, it is unclear *why* that layout has a `<fragment>` element in it, since the layout has nothing else of value. And I am not certain if you can use a fragment in a `PopupWindow` anyway. I would not be surprised if you have to get rid of all of that and use Maps V2's version of `MapView`.

Answer (score 0):

Try Support fragment
`<android.support.v4.app.Fragment />` instead of `<fragment />` since you are using a FragmentActivity and SupportMapFragment.